# RMagick error with animated gif

Tags: ruby, image-processing, imagemagick, rmagick, animated-gif

I have encountered ImageMagickError when using RMagick to read a animated GIF of http://us.i1.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/mesg/emoticons7/20.gif ([image: The problem image]).

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'rmagick'
url = 'http://us.i1.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/mesg/emoticons7/20.gif'
Magick::Image.from_blob(open(url).read)
```

It gives an error message like "`in from_blob : corrupt image @ error/gif.c/ReadGIFImage/1331 (Magick::ImageMagickError)`".

I have read the document ( http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#from_blob ) and it says `from_blob` can handle an animated GIF.

The code works with many images but this one. Anyone RMagick user have some idea about the error?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use simply `Magick::Image.read(url)`